# Give an example of a polynomial whose Galois group is isomorphic to $D_{10}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I have been spending my leisure time determining the subfield lattices and corresponding Galois subgroup lattices of some splitting fields of polynomials.  I have made the lattice diagrams for the "typical" examples that seem to be given in most of the texts that I have browsed:

x^2 - 2 ~ C_2,

x^3 - 2 ~ S_3,

x^4 - 2 ~ D_8,

the nth cyclotomic polynomials for various samll n ~ (Z_n,*),

(x^2-2)(x^2-3) ~ C_2 X C_2,

(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-5) ~ C_2 X C_2 X C_2,

x^4 - 10x^2 + 20 ~ C_4.

I would like to know if anyone agrees with the isomorphisms above.
Also, I would like to know of an example of a polynomial whose splitting field has Galois group that is isomorphic to D_10.  Since D_10 has only 8 subgroups it seems like this might provide a reasonable exercise in constructing the subfield lattice.

Comment: The isomorphisms you mentioned are all correct.

Comment: Please learn enough TeX for your question to be readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following polynomial with galois group $D_{10}$ was found by PARI/GP :

```
? f
%34 = x^5 - 2*x^4 + x^3 + x^2 - x + 1
? polgalois(f)
%35 = [10, 1, 1, "D(5) = 5:2"]
?
```

So, $$x^5-2x^4+x^3+x^2-x+1$$ is an example. I approved the galois-group with GAP.

Comment: OK Thanks.  x^5 - 2*x^4 + x^3 + x^2 - x + 1 has exactly one real root and 2 pairs of nonreal complex conjugates.  I can see that 4 of the 10 automorphisms must be the identitiy map, the map f_1 sending one complex root to its conjugate, the map f_2 sending the other complex root to its conjugate, and f_1*f_2.  I have no idea what the other automorphisms would be.?

Comment: Complex conjugation is a $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism that corresponds to a 2+2 cycle in the embedding of the Galois group into $S_n$. Since the discriminant is $47^2$, we know the Galois group embeds inside $A_5$. The hard part is showing the Galois group can't be all of $A_5$. Anyone have a clue on that?